# Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository';

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-05 09:53:05.348 ERROR 46991 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.cassandra.springbootcassandrademo.repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on CassandraRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableCassandraRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2fe1348e): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

From your error message the problem is that it cannot find the cassandra instance running on localhost.

```
Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=2fe1348e)
```

If your host is somewhere other than localhost, you'll need to set the spring.data.cassandra.contact-points in your configuration file or set up a bean to create the Cassandra Cluster or Session (depending on which version of Spring boot you are using).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today. In my case may be it was some internal issue of spring boot itself. I Solved by changing the spring-boot version in **pom.xml**.
It was

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>     
</parent>
```

I changed the version to

```
<version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
```

And it worked.